# Java Tomcat embedded web app 404

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications

Some time ago I wrote java smart house web app with client and server application. Everything was working just fine. Now I need to setup client  again and I am stumbling against http 404 error after localhost:8080 or localhost:8080/smartHouse.I tried to figure it out myself but I don't hava any idea what is actually wrong

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "SmartHouse",
    urlPatterns = {"/smartHouse"}
)
public class SHServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

Main/Tomecat:

```
public class Main {
public static final Optional<String> port = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("PORT"));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String contextPath = "/";
    String appBase = ".";
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port.orElse("8080") ));
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(appBase);

    tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, appBase);
    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
}
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SmartHouseClient</groupId>
    <artifactId>SmartHouseClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.57</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SmartHouse-app</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>SmartHouse-app-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for any tips and help !

EDIT: My code is similar to ( as it was based on ) tutorial from this website: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html#section3. After completing all tutorials step again it turn out that the app still don't work. It is possible to download this app and test it yourself here http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/files/employees-app.zip

Comment: This can be caused by any of many things... Are you launching your application from the directory that's set as appBase?

Comment: I'm just simply running generated artifact (ofc located in targets) .  If it will help I foun old tutorial I was using to create this app : http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html#section9

Comment: Are you actually serving an HTML page or some response for these endpoints `/` and `/smartHouse`?

Comment: Yep my app is similar to the one provided in the tutorial link. ( what is really interesting the steps showed in this tutorial result in the same error ) I can put the link to github repo if it will help

Comment: Anything in the logs?